# Distortion when viewing leaflet geojson

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis, shapefile

I've been trying to view some gis files with leaflet in my browser. When I view them in some other pages like http://lsi.iiit.ac.in:8095/lsiviewer or http://mapshaper.org/ they display correctly. However, when I view them in leaflet the file doesn't display as it should - they are distorted.

Here is the shapefile archives:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BxYlN9E2saSzSnEwMHVoRGhBYTQ?usp=sharing

Here are 2 screenshots of the "good" and the "bad" ways how the shapes  display: 
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1eH89girZ7uGEos87SCY-t26IaWdauSc3?usp=sharing

My code:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import * as shp from 'shpjs';
import * as L from 'leaflet';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-oportunidaddetalles',
  templateUrl: 'oportunidaddetalles.html',
})
export class OportunidaddetallesPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {

    var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [51.505, -0.09],
        zoom: 13
    });


    shp("./assets/my/RETINA").then(function(geojson){
      L.geoJSON(geojson).addTo(map);
   });


    }

}
```

```css
#map{
    position: relative !important;
    height: 1200px;
    width: 900px;
  }
```

```html
<!--this is from the ionic page, so it's just a div-->
<div id="map">

</div>
```

Comment: It would help if you attach screenshots of the "good" and "distorted" shapes.

Comment: Please import your images directly into your post, rather than sharing through an external link. SO provides its own image hosting service when you use the image inclusion button in the post editing form.

Comment: What's the CRS of your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspecting your SHP file using a conversion tool like https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/shp-to-geojson, it appears that it uses *Belge 1972 / Belgian Lambert 72 (EPSG:31370)* coordinate system.

The library [Shapefile.js](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/shapefile-js) (i.e. npm package [`"shpjs"`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shpjs)) that you use seems to expect this projection information in a `*.dbf` file, which is missing in your data.

Once your SHP file is converted to *WGS 84 (EPSG:4326)*, it displays fine in Leaflet:

[image: Screenshot correct shapes]

You can use the above linked tool to convert your file directly into GeoJSON and WGS 84 coordinate system, so that you no longer need Shapefile.js.

Comment: Thank you very much @ghybs , the problem was that I was using EPSG:31300 when Leaflet uses EPSG:3857 ("Web Mercator"). You guided me in the correct direction